# Assigning week numbers in a time series to obtain weekly average price

Tags: r, date, time-series

Let's say I have a time series with daily data (business days), and I would like to organize the data by business weeks. (Monday-Friday) in a similar fashion as the one in this webpage from the EIA on futures prices of crude oil:

http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=RCLC1&f=D

As you can see the prices are nicely organized by weeks in this webpage.
Is there any function in R that could organize the data in a similar fashion?

You can obtain the data in .xls format at:
http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist_xls/RCLC1d.xls

What I would like to do is to assign a week number to each daily observation something like this: (Look at the weeks column)

```
     Date Price weeks  day
 1983-04-04 29.44    1   Monday
 1983-04-05 29.71    1   Tuesday
 1983-04-06 29.92    1   Wednesday
 1983-04-07 30.17    1   Thursday
 1983-04-08 30.38    1   Friday
 1983-04-11 30.26    2   Monday
 ...
 ...
```

So far I have used the week function of the lubridate package but is not working well. It seems like once a year hits the 53rd week the function fails to initiate properly the week of the following year.

I have been trying to stay away from rep, seq /5 or /7 kind of solutions since there may be some observations that I may need to filter from the data later on, so I would like to have a solution that doesn't depend on the particular vector of my data but rather I would prefer the solution to be more general, that is to depend on the date class, i.e POSIcxt, xts or zoo class

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see your comments below but you still do not say what you want as a number for the the weeks that span a year increment.

Comment: So you do not want a number; you just want the week spans

Comment: If you want to assign a number to the weeks that sapn two years, then YOU WILL NEED TO TELL US WHAT NUMBER TO ASSIGN.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this work?:

```
as.POSIXlt()$yday %/% 7
```

I realize that it does have part of what you wanted to avoid but it does draw its starting point from a recognized class. For your data noting that I read it in with `colClasses=c("Date", "numeric","numeric","character")` :

```
> 1 + as.POSIXlt(dat$Date)$yday %/% 7
[1] 14 14 14 14 14 15
```

If you want to replicate those interval labels, try adding multiples of 7 to any Monday and Friday:

```
 paste(as.Date(strptime("1983 Apr- 4",format="%Y %b- %d"))+(39)*7, 
         " to ", 
         as.Date(strptime("1983 Apr- 8",format="%Y %b- %d"))+(39)*7,
         sep="")
@[1] "1984-01-02 to 1984-01-06" #  The first new year change
 paste(as.Date(strptime("1983 Apr- 4",format="%Y %b- %d"))+(39+52)*7, 
         " to ", 
         as.Date(strptime("1983 Apr- 8",format="%Y %b- %d"))+(39+52)*7,
         sep="")
#[1] "1984-12-31 to 1985-01-04"  #  The second new year change
```

Here's a function that will accept an integer vector:

```
from8Apr83dts <- function(numwks) { 
     paste(as.Date(strptime("1983 Apr- 4",format="%Y %b- %d"))+(numwks)*7, 
          " to ", 
          as.Date(strptime("1983 Apr- 8",format="%Y %b- %d"))+(numwks)*7,
          sep="") 
                                   }
# Usage
from8Apr83dts(39:40)
#[1] "1984-01-02 to 1984-01-06" "1984-01-09 to 1984-01-13"
```

Comment: From the linked example data, it looks like @AndresT wants these to be work weeks, so that Monday through Friday will always be in the same week.  One possibility for that would be to use `strftime(as.POSIXlt(dat$Date), format="%W")`, but that doesn't always link the days in a week that spans two years (e.g. Monday Dec 31st with Friday, Jan 4th).  Maybe the @AndresT could clarify what he wants done with such weeks...

Comment: You said you wanted it to look just like the example you offered. That what I did. The weekly intervals match those in the website you linked to. If you want something different then provide clear instructions. And anyway I get weekdays(as.Date("1984-01-02"))
[1] "Monday"